# Retrieve Data from a Specific Database

Tags: sql-server-2012

**Goal**:

I want to retrieve the value of `[data].[Mobiles]` when you use a query document that is for the database `[test]` (`use [test]`)

**Problem**:

Based on picture two, I cannot retrieve the value from the database. Don't know what is the problem? The database `[wwtest]` does exist.

Picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2:

[image]

Comment: is on the same server? dbo is the schema  ? or [data] is the schema ? Did you try with [wwtest].[data].[Mobiles] ?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same server.

Comment: It works with "[wwtest].[data].[Mobiles] " Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `[wwtest].[data].[Mobiles]`

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the three-part naming syntax:

```
<database>.<schema>.<object>
  wwtest  .  data  . Mobiles
```

...however you seem to be confused between your schema naming. In the table `data.Mobiles`, `data` is the schema, not `dbo`, so the naming should be `wwtest.data.Mobiles`.

`dbo` is also a schema, so there is no need to include it in your query when you are selecting from an object in a different schema.

Otherwise you end up with a completely different naming convention. The four-part naming sytax is as follows:

```
<server>.<database>.<schema>.<object>
 wwtest .   dbo    .  data  . Mobiles
```

In your example, you are looking for a database called `dbo` on a server called `wwtest`.

That is why you get the error:

> Could not find server 'wwtest' in sys.servers.

Comment: +1 for better understood database schema with example dbo.